# Is it possible to apply patch to single module of apache?

Tags: apache, patch

We are trying to apply security patches to apache. After googling, I found that, in-order to apply patches, one need to apply patch to apache source; compile it and build it again. This will lead to fresh installation.

Is there any way to directly apply patches to existing apache installation ?

We do not want to re-install apache again, as that may remove some custom configurations like virtual hosts and ssl configuration.

Help is appriciated...

Comment: These days, if you compile apache yourself, instead of using a pre-packed distro, you seem to be doing something wrong (except for special cases when you're writing apache modules yourself or something like that). Especially if you have no clue how to save configuration files before the update process and restore them later.